# Is it possible to get the function name from the mangled string

Tags: c++, introspection, abi, demangler

This question is a continuation of [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914938/return-type-in-demangled-member-function-name/44914982#44914982), where a code to demangle a function-name given by the `backtrace` function is presented.

I wonder whether there is a way to get **the name and the namespaces of a callable object**. Here we assume that the function does have a name and that it is possible to demangle its name with `abi::__cxa_demangle` (for example, it's not a lambda function).

Furthermore, would it be possible to get a list of the namespaces in which the function is?

Comment: You won't be able to differ namespace from a class/struct name, but otherwise the code from your previous question handles the case just fine - all you need to do is to split the name by `::`.

Comment: Observe that if you have a template function then parsing the name of the function of the string is not that easy since the first part of the demangled name is the return type. Furthermore, separating the name by spaces does not work either, since the demangling function adds spaces when you have templates of templates like in `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` (gotta love C++98)

Comment: Is your request limited to builds with debug symbols?

Comment: I do have the control over all the library and how's the project built, so any solution would do the trick, as long as it is not extremely costly. Right now for this to work, as I pointed out in the other post, the only requirement is to have access to `abi::__cxa_demangle`, `backtrace` and build the project with `-rdynamic` (although, of course, I do not intend ot create a portable solution at all, as long as it works for clang and gcc I'm more than fine)